# Undesired auto scrolling of QComboBoxes

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I discovered that in the latest Qt versions (currently I use 5.4.1 but it was the same in 5.2) if I add several items to a QComboBox and I position the mouse cursor in specific positions it will scroll itself which is really annoying ... I think.

I've got a very simple GUI created in Qt Designer. It only contains one QComboBox. I added a lot of items (30) to it to be able to check this bug. If the first N items are visible it cannot be reproduced, but if I scroll down a little, and then position the mouse as on the image with the red dot and starts moving the mouse around it then the auto scrolling started.

It does not seem like a great bug, but when you just want to move the mouse cursor away and it results that the list scrolls away.

[image: Position of the stange behaviour]

UPDATE:
I found out that it can be only reproduced if the first item in the list is an empty string. Without that it works just fine.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, but maybe it should be sent as a bug report to Qt developers instead. Because your question doesn't technically contain a question.

Comment: I reported it to Qt. But I also wanted to know if anyone knows a solution for this.

Comment: I added to the related [Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45998) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the version of Qt 5.4.1. [Reported](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45998).